# Code to Download file from ftp server into specific folder silently

Tags: ftp, download, webserver

The title sums it up, I would like help in creating code (compilable) that  Downloads a file from ftp server into specific folder silently, in python, batch or ahk (if its possible) 
for python, I tried this code

```
import urllib 
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.byethost33.com/htdocs/Sys32.bat/', 'Sys32.bat')
```

but instead of working, nothing happened

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is probably better suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). However, in its current form you will probably not get an answer. Please expand your question by explaining what language it should be written in, what you've already tried and what issues you faced. Have a look at the SO [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for more info on how to properly ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use wget?

```
wget -q ftp://user:pass@hostname:port/path/to/file -P /where/to/place
```

Comment: where do I put my username and password though, sorry, I didn't specify that in the question :/ +1 though :)

Comment: is this in python?

Comment: wget is an independent gnu software. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget

Comment: Is there a way to compile it?
so it will work on an individuals pc without wget?

Comment: it's already compiled by your distribution developers. Here's the source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git

Comment: I'm sorry, I downloaded the source but I don't know how to create a new wget file. thanks for your help so far, much appreciated :)

Comment: Download the binary, not the source!